# Error en wsdl de la Dian "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."

Tags: soap, wsdl

estoy intentando firmar el envio de una factura para la dian, siguiendo la documentacion para configurar el soapUi el envio se hace bien, pero al momento de hacerlo en codigo (Node) no funciona, usando soap me aparece el error 400 bad request, y usando fetch sale el xml de respuesta con el error antes mensionado, alguien que me pueda ayudar

Codigo fech

```
const p12 = require('p12-pem')
const https = require('https');
const { pemKey, pemCertificate, commonName } = p12.getPemFromP12("path/cert.p12", 'passCert');
        const message = `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wcf="http://wcf.dian.colombia">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
           <wcf:SendTestSetAsync>
              <wcf:contentFile>?</wcf:contentFile>
              <wcf:testSetId>?</wcf:testSetId>
           </wcf:SendTestSetAsync>
        </soap:Body>
     </soap:Envelope>`

        const certBuffer = Buffer.from(pemCertificate, 'utf8');
        const agent = new https.Agent({
            cert: certBuffer,
            key: pemKey,
        });


        const fetchConfig = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8' },
            body: message,
            agent: agent
        }

        const result = await fetch(process.env.URL_SOAP, fetchConfig)

        if (result.ok === false) {
            const error = await result.text()
            console.log(error)

        }

        resolve(true)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]